# Magento - Adding products from CSV - Loop issue

Tags: php, magento, csv

I have a CSV file with a header row. The code puts the column names as the $Key and $postion is the values. This works okay.

This is the loop creating the string of attributes to add to the product. When i "echo $sets" it displays correctly

```
foreach ($each_csv as $position => $details) {
        $sets .= ->set$position('$details')}
```

$sets is creating the ->set code for the product. How do I implement the loop values into the product set function

```
$product->setWebsiteIds(array(1))
        ->setTypeId('simple') 
        ->setMediaGallery (array('images'=>array (), 'values'=>array ()))
        // How can I add the looped values here from the array
```

. Full Code Below

```
<?php
include ("../config/init.php");
Mage::app()->setCurrentStore(Mage_Core_Model_App::ADMIN_STORE_ID);
$product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product');
$rows = array_map('str_getcsv', file('prouduct_ids.csv'));
$header = array_shift($rows);
$csv = array();
foreach ($rows as $row) {
    $csv[] = array_combine($header, $row);
}

//print_r($csv);
reset($csv);
$dataSetCount = count($csv);
echo "<h1>There are $dataSetCount products</h1>";
$i = 0;
foreach ($csv as $each_csv) {
    $i++;
    echo "<h2>csv $i</h2>";

    if(!$product->getIdBySku($each_csv['Sku'])){
        echo $each_csv['Sku'] . " - Already in website";
    } else {
        foreach ($each_csv as $position => $details) {
            $sets .=->set$position('$details')}

        $product->setWebsiteIds(array(1)) //website ID the product is assigned to, as an array
        ->setTypeId('simple') //product type
        ->setMediaGallery (array('images'=>array (), 'values'=>array ()));
        //media gallery initialization
        $product->save();
        unset($sets);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to use the `$product->setData('data_key', 'value')` function.

For example, this function:

`$product->setTypeId('simple')`

Is the exact same as this function:

`$product->setData('type_id', 'simple')`

Keep in mind that a capital letter represents an underscore in the attribute name.  `typeId` is `type_id` because the `I` in `Id` is capitalized.

The code in your functon will look like this:

```
[...]
foreach ($each_csv as $position => $details) {
    $sets .= $product->setData($position, $details)

[...]
```

Where `$position` is the **attribute code**, and `$details` is the **attribute value**.

Comment: I dont get any more errors while using your code. How can I see the results, before it goes to " $product->save();"
I run it, and it gives no errors directly, but no product was added

Comment: You may be missing some required attributes for saving the new products.  See this article and make sure you include everything: http://inchoo.net/ecommerce/magento/programming-magento/programatically-manually-creating-simple-magento-product/